# How do I get a print of the functions called in a C++ program under Linux?

Tags: c++, c, debugging, trace

What I want is a mix of what can be obtained by a static code analysis like Doxygen and the stackframe you can see when using GDB. I know which problematic function I'm debugging and I want to see the neighbourhood of the function calls that guided the execution to this function call. For instance, running a simple HelloWorld! would output something like:

```
main:
   Greeter::Greeter()
   Greeter::printHello()
   Greeter::printWorld()
```

denoting that from the main function, the constructor was called and then the printHello and printWorld functions where called. Notice that in GDB if I break at printWorld I won't be able to see in the stackframe that printHello was called.

Any ideas about how to trace function calls without going through the pain of inserting log messages in a myriad of source files?

Thanks!!

Comment: In what context do you want to be able to do this?  If you're in GDB, then you have `backtrace`...  What else do you want?

Comment: I want to trace the context in which a function was called in a very big program in order to figure which variables/objects where modified before the function's call. The stack trace by itself is not enough because I could be missing function calls at the same frame level but that happened before my function's call.

Comment: step trough the program with the debugger, and you will see which functions were called... or add debug messages to the function which calls your function..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From reading the question I understand that you want a list of all relevant functions executed in order as they're executed.

Unfortunately there is no application to generate this list automatically, but there are helper macros to save you a lot of time.  Define a single macro called LOGFUNCTION or whatever you want and define it as:

```
#define LOGFUNCTION printf("In %s (%s:%d)\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __FILE__, __LINE__);
```

Now you do have to paste the line `LOGFUNCTION` wherever you want a trace to be added.

wherever you see fit.

see http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html and http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html

Comment: It's a pitty it can not be done programmatically but at least now I know it can not be done.

Answer (score 4):

The [`-finstrument-functions` option](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.2/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html) to `gcc` instructs the compiler to call a user-provided profiling function at every function entry and exit.

You could use this to write a function that just logs every function entry and exit.

Answer (score 0):

GDB features a stack trace, it does what you ask for.

Comment: Ah, OK, well, then it's indeed not what you're after. You should've made it clear what you were after from the beginning. I use my own logging class for that (although I need to add extra code myself wherever I want something to be logged). I haven't heard of any utility that would do it out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

What he wants is to obtain tha info (for example, backtrace from gdb) but printed in a 'nicer' format than gdb do.
I think you can't. I mean, maybe there is some type of app that trace your application and do something like that, but I never hear about something like that.

The best thing you can do is use GDB, maybe create some type of bash script that use gdb to obtain the info and print it out in the way you like.

Of course, your application MUST be compiled with debug symbols (-g param to gcc).

Comment: The only way I know of to get a "nicer" output from gdb is to use it via some good IDE. Code::Blocks is my bet here, as it's both readable and lets you jump directly to the lines that are in the stack trace. I doubt it'll get "nicer" than that :)

Comment: I never did something like that, but I thought that maybe you will be able to found any way to parse that in something nicer to you. The answer about the macro was good, but you said that you didnt want to paste logs everywhere...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what the problem is with gdb's backtrace, but maybe a profiler is closer to what you want? For example, using valgrind:

```
valgrind --tool cachegrind ./myprogram
kcachegrind callgrind.out.NNNN
```

Comment: Valgrind aggregates the info. I need an orderly printed version of all the functions that were called in a program's run.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use gprof to generate a call graph? You can also convert gprof output to something easier on the eye with [gprof2dot](http://code.google.com/p/jrfonseca/wiki/Gprof2Dot) for example.